# Display a list from Python as flow style inside a block style yaml file (ruamel.yaml)

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml to create a YAML file from a Python dictionary. Within the dictionary, there's a list as the value for the 'type' key. I've been looking all day now for examples to solve my problem, but can't find anything in the docs.

I've been trying to get a YAML file output like this:

```
 some_key:
  - id: 1059
    parameter: Paramter1
    unit: kg
    type: [A, B, C, 1, 2, 3]
```

That means the list after type is a flow-style element within the block style, which is the actual reason I switched to `ruamel.yaml`, because I read that it might be possible as opposed to PyYAML ([Mixing block and flow formatting in YAML with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976149/mixing-block-and-flow-formatting-in-yaml-with-python)). But in there I couldn't find what I am trying to do.

What I (unsurprisingly) get when I call

```
yaml.dump()
```

on the dictionary is

```
some_key:
  - id: 1059
    parameter: Paramter1
    unit: kg
    type:
          - A 
          - B
          - C
          - '1'
          - '2'
          - '3'
```

Does anyone have a clue how this is solvable? A useful information might or might not be, that the list concerned could also be converted to different formats (e.g string), I get it from a csv-sheet.

UPDATE, here is a code example of what I've been trying:

A CSV-line looks like this:

```
"","",Parameter 1,Dropdown,kg,"","","A,B,C,1,2,3"
```

and in the conversion.py something like:

```
with open(csv_filename, "r") as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
data = {"some_key": []}
for position, line in enumerate(reader):
        if line[3] == "Dropdown":
            select_options = []
            for item in line[7].split(","):
                select_options.append(item)
            select_options = [x.strip(" ") for x in select_options]
            type = f"{select_options}"
        dict = {
            "id": "tbd",
            "parameter": line[2].strip(" "),
            "unit": line[4].strip(" "),
            "type": type,
        }
        data["some_key"].append(dict)
doc = yaml.dump(data, file)
```

Comment: It would have been better to include a minimal program and  minimal CSV input to show how you get the output you do. That way we can provide you with an answer more directly usable in your circumstances.

Comment: You are right. I added it to my original post, so that someone who might encounter a similar problem sees what I tried

Comment: One thing you can do to get numbers in `section_options` as numbers is to `try:\n item=int(item)\n except ValueError:\n pass` before appending. (Making \n into real newlines and properly indented).

Comment: That's what I actually did in my code (except for the \n) after your reply. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to define numbers as numbers, and not as strings, to get
the output of those non-quoted ( `3` instead of `'3'` )

Second you need to call `yaml.indent()` as the sequence indent of 3 positions
with an offset for the sequence delimiter of 1, is non-standard.

Then to fine control a single list flow style you need to add that list as a
`CommentedSeq` and call the `set_flow_style()` methode on its `fa` attribute:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def seq(*l):
    s = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq(l)
    s.fa.set_flow_style()
    return s

data = dict(some_key=[{'id': 1059,
                       'parameter': 'Paramter1',
                       'unit': 'kg',
                       'type': seq('A', 'B', 'C', 1, 2 ,3)}])


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=3, offset=1)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
some_key:
 - id: 1059
   parameter: Paramter1
   unit: kg
   type: [A, B, C, 1, 2, 3]
```

In your example, you could have set `yaml.default_flow_style = None` before
dumping and use a "normal" list. But that will affected all other "leaf-node"
lists and dicts as well.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, I don't think I would have found that anywhere!